# What is the meaning of "he is late on his front"?

Tags: meaning

I saw it in a subtitle of a movie. I searched Google for it, but found nothing.
So I thought it might be wrong or it is not quite uncommon.
Then I decided asking here.

The context is: a guy #1 owes someone some drug pill, and the one who said this, said that the guy #1 is late on his front, as he is owing him money.

Comment: My guess is it's either *actual*, or *made-up-for-the-movie* slang deriving from guy#1 not having paid his [*money "up front"*](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1342234) when he was supposed to (to pay for the drugs he wants). I doubt it has much currency, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=front) has as one of the definitions of front, "To advance somone money/drugs", so I would hazard a guess that he is late advancing (or repaying an advance) of money/drugs

Answer (score 0):

I guess the expression is derived from the following idiomatic use of *front*:

To [front someone some  amount of money](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/front):

> to provide an advance payment of some amount to someone. The buyer fronted me half the purchase price as a favor.

Source:McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.